# Multiple-choice test paper in PHP by using Database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm just a beginner of PHP and I am working for making a multiple-choice type question paper. And I want to stores answers of these question in the database and also want to fetch result from database. And also I want to show result of attempt in percentage e.g. Your result is 40%.

I'm running PHP on WAMP server.

Comment: Ankit, this is far too broad. Would make a start on this and ask a question if you get stuck? As it stands it is hard to know how to advise you, other than to find some good database/web tutorials to show you how to build web apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow, we are here to help you correct your bugs and help you if you get stuck in coding. We are not freelancers, so please do not ask such questions which literally mean "do my homework!".

But hey, let me give you a basic info on how you should start up. First create a php page with form which contains all questions at once or like a wizard (depends on your needs). Later, you need to create a database, with two tables (maybe more) which are questions and answers. These shouldn't contains huge amounts of html chunks, but should be straight questions and answers with a foreign key to link them. Then use php to generate random questions and answers and use normal post/get (usually not user friendly) or AJAX (better performance).

If you get stuck in any of the steps above, then come back to StackOverflow and share your query with invalid codes and similar. Hoping this was helpful :)